# Finding subsets in Erlang, please help me optimize the solution

Tags: math, erlang, subset

Full disclosure. This was an interview/prescreen question which I failed to solve during the interview. I decided to implement it in Erlang for my own benefit.

### Here's the problem statement:

> You must find number of subsets of an array where the largest number is the sum of the remaining numbers. For example, for an input of:
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
>
> the subsets would be
>
> 1 + 2 = 3
>
> 1 + 3 = 4
>
> 2 + 4 = 6
>
> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

### Here's my solution:

```erlang
% credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459152/erlang-listsindex-of-function
index_of(Item, List) -> index_of(Item, List, 1).
index_of(_, [], _)  -> not_found;
index_of(Item, [Item|_], Index) -> Index;
index_of(Item, [_|Tl], Index) -> index_of(Item, Tl, Index+1).

% find sums
findSums(L) ->
    Permutations=generateAllCombos(L),
    lists:filter(fun(LL) -> case index_of(lists:sum(LL), L) of
                    not_found -> false;
                    _ -> true
                end
        end, Permutations).


% generate all combinations of size 2..legnth(L)-1
generateAllCombos(L) ->
    NewL=L--[lists:last(L)],
    Sizes=lists:seq(2,length(NewL)),
    lists:flatmap(fun(X) -> simplePermute(NewL,X) end, Sizes).

% generate a list of permutations of size R from list L
simplePermute(_,R) when R == 0 ->
    [[]];

simplePermute(L,R) ->
    [[X|T] || X <- L, T<-simplePermute(lists:nthtail(index_of(X,L),L),R-1)].
```

Here's an example run:

### Example:

```
18> maxsubsetsum_app:findSums([1,2,3,4,6]).
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

### Questions

1. Dear Erlangers (Erlangists?) does this look like canonical Erlang to you?
2. Is there a better way to say what I did?
3. Is there a cleaner over all solution (this is quite brute force).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more elegant looking version.

In this version I am assuming only positive numbers with the hope of getting some speed up. Also, I'm a bit tired so it may have some small typos, but is mostly correct :)

```
get_tails([]) -> [];
get_tails([_]) -> [];
get_tails([X:XS]) -> [[X:XS],get_tails(XS)].

get_sums([]) -> [];
get_sums([_]) -> [];
get_sums([X:XS]) -> [get_sums_worker(X,XS):get_sums(XS)]

get_sums_worker(S,_) when S < 0 -> [];
get_sums_worker(S,_) when S == 0 -> [[]];
get_sums_worker(S,[X:XS]) when S > 0 ->
    get_sums_worker(S, XS) ++ [[X:L] || L <- get_sums_worker(S - X, XS)].

sums(A0) ->
    A = lists:reverse(lists:sort(A0)),
    B = get_tails(A),
    lists:flatmap(fun get_sums/1, B).
```

I am not sure how much this can be sped up, since I suspect that the knapsack problem reduces to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is your algorithm:

1. Generating all combinations (2^n)
2. Summing each set of combinations (n)
3. Searching the list for each sum (n)

That looks like it's `n*2^n`.  I think that's as fast as you can go in terms of computation, since you have to try on the order of all combinations for every number in the list.  Maybe someone can correct me on that.

However, your space efficiency seems to be `2^n`, since it stores all combinations, which is unnecessary.

This is what I came up with, which only accumulates results:

1. For each item, search the rest of the list for combinations that add up to it.
2. In order to find combinations, subtract the first number of the list from the target number, and search the rest of the list for combinations that add up to the difference.

```
-module(subsets).

-export([find_subsets/1]).


find_subsets(NumList) ->
  ReverseSorted = lists:reverse(lists:sort(NumList)),
  find_each_subset(ReverseSorted, []).

find_each_subset([], Subsets) ->
  Subsets;
find_each_subset([First | ReverseSorted], Subsets) ->
  [ { First, recurse_find_subsets(First, ReverseSorted, [])} | find_each_subset(ReverseSorted, Subsets)].

recurse_find_subsets(_Target, [], Sets) ->
  Sets;
recurse_find_subsets(Target, [Target | _Numbers], []) ->
  [[Target]];
recurse_find_subsets(Target, [First | Numbers], Sets) when Target - First > 0 ->
  Subsets = recurse_find_subsets(Target - First, Numbers, []),
  NewSets = lists:map(fun(Subset) -> [ First | Subset] end, Subsets),
  recurse_find_subsets(Target, Numbers, lists:append(NewSets, Sets));
recurse_find_subsets(Target, [_First | Numbers], Sets) ->
  recurse_find_subsets(Target, Numbers, Sets).
```

Output:

```
5> subsets:find_subsets([6,4,3,2,1]).
[{6,[[3,2,1],[4,2]]},{4,[[3,1]]},{3,[[2,1]]},{2,[]},{1,[]}]
```