# Find the position of a field in a list Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this list

```
[id,container,feed_id,prev,next,feeds,name,street,street_no,
 firstname,lastname,email,password,phone...]
```

and I want to get the position of various elements, like name, which would be 7.

How do I get the position of elements in a list with Erlang?

```
lists:member(name, List).
```

This only returns whether an element is part of the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erlang lists:index\_of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459152/erlang-listsindex-of-function)

Answer (score 1):

If it's likely that you want to look up the index for several items, or even all, and perhaps also do this repeatedly, it would be best to create an index mapping:

```
Map = maps:from_list(lists:zip(List, lists:seq(1, length(List))))
```

You can then keep this map around, and use it like this:

```
Pos = maps:get(Element, Map)
```